# <p:fileUpload/> не работает

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Имеется p:dialog. Внутри него есть форма для загрузки изображения.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUploadImage">
                        <p:fileUpload id="imageUpload" label="Load" fileUploadListener="#{imageController.handleFileUpload}" update="messagesImage bookNewImage" sizeLimit="#{imageController.imageMaxSize}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" multiple="false" auto="true"/>  
                        <p:graphicImage value="#{imageController.uploadedImage}" library="images" width="110" height="150" id="bookNewImage"/>
                        <p:messages id="messagesImage" showDetail="true" for="formUploadImage"/>
</h:form>
```

Данная форма находится в другой форме. То есть структура получается такая:

```
<p:dialog>
   <h:form>
       <h:form id="formUploadImage>
       </h:form>
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

p:dialog подключается на основной странице через `<ui:include src="edit.xhtml"/>`

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку выбора файла и выбираю нужный мне файл, то в джава бине должен автоматически выполняться метод, но он не выполняется (посему и его код думаю постить бесполезно для понимания проблемы). Буквально никаких ошибок в консоли ЖС в браузере, никаких ошибок в консоли сервера (glassfish) — вообще ничего. С данным [тредом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded) ознакомлен, но ничего из приведенных советов не помогло. Скорее всего выделывается ajax, но как понять где именно не могу уже 3-ий день. Спасибо за любую информацию.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>library</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
    </context-param>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShowImage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.elibrary.web.servlets.ShowImage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Reader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.elibrary.web.servlets.Reader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>IFrame</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.elibrary.controllers.IFrame</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShowImage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ShowImage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Reader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Reader</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>IFrame</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/IFrame</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
            <role-name>admins</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admins</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Library</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
    <error-page>
         <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
         <location>/error/expired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.xhtml</location>    
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.elibrary.web.nls.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>books</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/books.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>books</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/books.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/pages/books.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```

edit.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
     <h:head>
        <title>Book edit</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:dialog id="editDialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlgEditBook" dynamic="true" resizable="true" header="#{msg.edit_book}" closable="true">

            <h:form id="formEditBook"  rendered="#{bookListController.editMode}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="col1, col2" styleClass="edit_book_table" >
                    <p:panel id="imagePanel">
                        <p:graphicImage  value="#{imageController.defaultImage}" width="110" height="150" id="bookImage"/>
                        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUploadImage">
                            <p:fileUpload id="imageUpload" label="Load" fileUploadListener="#{imageController.handleFileUpload}" update="messagesImage bookNewImage" sizeLimit="#{imageController.imageMaxSize}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" multiple="false" auto="true"/>  
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{imageController.uploadedImage}" library="images" width="110" height="150" id="bookNewImage"/>
                            <p:messages id="messagesImage" showDetail="true" for="formUploadImage"/>
                        </h:form>    
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel>
                        <p:panelGrid id="bookDetails" columns="2" >
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.book_name}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>
                            <p:inputText id="inputBookName" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.name}"  required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.required_field}" size="60"/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.author_name}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.author}" converter="#{authorController}">
                                <f:selectItems value="${authorController.selectItems}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>


                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.genre}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.genre}" converter="#{genreController}">
                                <f:selectItems value="${genreController.selectItems}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.publisher}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.publisher}" converter="#{publisherController}">
                                <f:selectItems value="${publisherController.selectItems}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.publish_year}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <p:inputText id="inputPublishYear" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.publishYear}" required="true"/>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.isbn}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <p:inputText id="inputIsbn" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.isbn}" required="true"/>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.page_count}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <p:inputText id="inputPageCount" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.pageCount}" required="true" />  

                            <p:outputLabel value="Text:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/PdfContent"  target="_blank" styleClass="pdf-link">                                                             
                                <p:outputLabel value="Show pdf"/>
                                <f:param name="id" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.id}"/>
                            </h:outputLink> 

                            <p:outputLabel/>

                            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUploadPdf">
                                <p:fileUpload  id="pdfUpload" label="Load PDF" fileUploadListener="#{contentController.handleFileUpload}" update="messages-pdf @form" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" multiple="false" auto="true" styleClass="pdf-upload"/>  
                                <h:outputLink id="uploadedPdfLink" value="#{request.contextPath}/UploadedPdf"  target="_blank" styleClass="pdf-link" rendered="#{contentController.showContent}">                                                             
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Show uploaded"/>
                                </h:outputLink> 
                                <p:messages id="messages-pdf" showDetail="true" for="formUploadPdf"/>
                            </h:form>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg.descr}:" styleClass="edit-title"/>

                            <p:panel styleClass="descr-text">
                                <p:inputTextarea id="inputDescr" value="#{bookListController.selectedBook.descr}" cols="60" rows="20" maxlength="1500" counter="counter" counterTemplate="#{msg.letters_left} {0}" autoResize="false"/>
                                <h:outputText id="counter" />  
                            </p:panel>


                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <p:commandButton styleClass="button-update" value="#{msg.save}" icon="ui-icon-check"  onclick="this.disabled=true;" update=":formEditBook :booksForm:booksList :booksCount :growlMessage">
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{imageController.saveListener()}"/>     
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{contentController.saveListener()}"/>     
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{bookListController.saveListener()}"/>     
                                </p:commandButton>
                                <p:commandButton action="#{bookListController.cancelModes()}" icon="ui-icon-close"  value="#{msg.cancel}" immediate="true" global="false">
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{imageController.clearListener()}"/>     
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{contentController.clearListener()}"/>     
                                </p:commandButton>    
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>  
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Библиотеки: omnifaces1.5, primefaces6.2, jsf 2.2. Страница xhtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При построении страницы допущена фундаментальная ошибка: согласно спецификаций, `HTML` форма не должна содержать других форм (см., например, вот это пояснение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/555970/1341148).
  При вложении одной формы в другую могут возникать любые непредвиденные проблемы или неожиданное поведение компонентов на форме.

**PS** В `JSF` зачастую практикуется объявление диалогов где-нибудь в конце страницы, где точно известно, что они не попадут внутрь формы. Это не обязательное условие, но обычно надёжнее относиться к диалогам как к практически отдельной странице и как бы выделять для них отдельное пространство.

Comment: С атрибутом `appendTo="@(body)"` в `p:dialog`, форма рендерится одна вроде как. Потом я брал выносил блок с загрузкой файлов в отдельную форму, и всё равно не работает. На совсем отдельной странице тоже не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте: 1. Тестируя на отдельной странице удалить с неё всё, кроме самого `fileUpload`. Обязательно отключить `template` страницы, если он есть. 2. Удалить максимально возможное кол-во сторонних библиотек, особенно как-то связанных с JSF. Чтобы при этом не "сломалась" сборка, можно удалять .jar файлы библиотек не из проекта (pom), а из развёрнутого приложения (обязательно перезапускать приложение). 3. Проверьте [матрицу совместимости](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Compatibility-Matrix) Omifaces - у Вас довольно старая версия используется

Comment: Создал совершенно новый проект с одной лишь подключённой библиотекой PF, и там создал небольшую страницу. UI компонент отрабатывает, кнопка для выбора файлов есть, прогресс-бар отрабатывает, через инструменты разработчика в хроме во вкладке Sources показывае, что файл был загружен, но метод из бина не вызывается. Спасибо за советы, хоть всё тщетно но натолкнуло на мысль, что это проблема сервера. На данный момент использую Glassfish 5. Попробую дома на TomCat'e — отпишусь.

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать убрать `multipart/form-data`. Там скорее всего через AJAX работает, и современных версиях Primefaces вроде не требуется дополнительных настроек для формы. `multipart/form-data` может "сломать" вызов метода.

Comment: Вы были совершенно правы, + у меня ещё были применены кастомные стилы к элементам PF. Удалил кастомные стили + убрал аттрибут enctype — всё заработало :) Спасибо большое! Я почти неделю искал в чём проблема...